# What's is the internal temperature of pancakes?

Tags: baking, temperature

I made pancakes made out of a nutritional shake but some of the health benefits disappear if heated over 115 degrees F. So wanted to know what the typical internal temp is for pancakes?

Answer (score 7):

The typical internal temperature at which most bread products are "done" is between 175-200˚F.  For a normal pancake batter that is enriched with butter, milk, and/or egg, it would likely fall at the lower end of that range.  However, the browned outer crust has likely reached significantly higher temperatures, in the 250-400˚F range.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, most guidelines for cooking pancakes recommend using a griddle temperature of 350°-375° F.  Cooking at lower temperatures yields tough pancakes.  Cooking at MUCH lower temperatures would keep your pancakes from forming in any real way.

If there is egg in the recipe for your pancakes, you would need to cook them to an internal temperature of at least 145° F for food safety reasons.  But a pancake cooked to 145° F would be terribly gooey on the inside.  A fully cooked pancake would certainly reach a higher internal temperature.

And while it would be difficult to measure the internal temperature of a pancake without special equipment (e.g. a temperature probe that registers internal temperature using a very tiny sensor that would fully fit inside a skinny little pancake), I think it is safe to say that the internal temperature of any cooked pancake would greatly exceed your 115° F limit for preservation of nutritional benefits.

Comment: Indeed, 115F is just kinda... warm. You can hold your hand in water at that temperature. Nothing really cooked is going to be below it. (In practice pancakes probably get reasonably close to boiling temperatures inside, I'm guessing.)

Comment: That would be a small temperature probe all right. Better to make a nutritious sauce.